# Why does Context line-break my quotation and leave the quotation sign on it's own row?

Tags: line-breaking, punctuation, context, quoting

Using Context to set a book I have the following problem: Context linebreaks some quotations in a way that makes the quotation sign (in my case a guillemet [[sic!](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemets#Guillemet_vs._guillemot)]) appear on its own row. How can i prevent this?

I guess I could in some way use a `\hbox{around the quote}` but I would like to prevent this from happening in the whole document. How can I achieve that?

[image: Above MWE compiled]

## NSMWE

(Not so minimal working example ...)

```
\enableregime   [utf-8]
\mainlanguage   [sv]

\setupbodyfont [cmr,10pt] % 10.6 för att fylla 64 sidor 

\setupindenting[9mm]

% Indentera kommande rader i stycken
\definestartstop
  [exdent]
  [before={\startnarrower[left]\setupindenting[-\leftskip,yes]},
   after=\stopnarrower]

\setupdelimitedtext[quotation:1][left=»,right=»]
\setupdelimitedtext[quotation:2][left=',right=']

%% Layout %%
\setuppapersize[A5][A5] % ,landscape
\setuplayout [location=middle,
    height=189mm, % höjd på text+sidfot+sidhuvud -- Dessa tre första är de enda som påverkar brödtextsfältets storlek
        width=95mm, % bredd på text
topspace=22mm, % utrymme över sidhuvud
    backspace=17mm, % utrymme mellan text och rygg
    headerdistance=10pt, % mellan sidhuvud och text
    header=10pt,
    footerdistance=4mm, % text till sidfot
    bottomspace=4mm, % mellan sidfot och sidslut
    footer=37mm,
    leftmargindistance=2mm, % text till vänstermarginal
    leftmargin=13mm,
    leftedge=2mm, % vänstermarg rygg
    rightmargindistance=2mm,
    rightmargin=32mm, %33 justera rightedge och margin efter skrivarens fysiska marginal
    rightedge=3mm, %2
    grid=yes,
    marking=on,]

\starttext

\indenting[yes]
När jag som liten uppgett att teckningen föreställer \quotation{Tomtarnas eld i skogen} kanske det inte alls var menat som en optisk liknelse av denna händelse, utan som en annan typ av {\em teckning} av tomtarnas eld i skogen.

\stoptext
```

Comment: A `\break` before the quotation is a workaround for this particular case.

Comment: A better workaround is to use `left=»\nobreak`.

Comment: @Marco That sounds like a solution to me, so many thanks! But I'm eager to hear about even more refined solution ... Acually I'm surprised that this break does occur at all, it seems just as unwanted as breaking a word with o-ne letter left on the first line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are two workarounds which both result in the quotation mark sticking to
the text.

The simplest way is to prevent the line break using `left=»\nobreak`. Another
solution is to set up the delimited text as part of the language setup using
`\setuplanguage`.

Here's a complete example:

```
\setuplayout [width=10cm]
\setuplanguage
  %% [sv]
  [leftquotation=»,
   rightquotation=»,
   leftquote=',
   rightquote=']

\starttext
  När jag som liten uppgett att teckningen föreställer
  \quotation{Tomtarnas eld i skogen} kanske det inte alls
  var menat som en optisk liknelse av denna händelse.
\stoptext
```

The `sv` argument is optional and applies the setup only for Swedish.

**Edit:** This issue was fixed in beta 2013.03.10 14:36. A break after the `left` symbol is now prevented by default.

Comment: Thank you @marco! Why does "setting up the delimited text as part of the language" prevent the splitting? What's the difference of defining it in `\setupdelimitedtext`?

Comment: @PetaspeedBeaver It inserts a `\nobreak` internally. However, I'm unsure if the behaviour you observed is intended. IMO it makes sense to always prevent a break in this case. You can reduce your code to a minimal example (10 lines is sufficient to demonstrate the issue) and post it on the context mailing list.